# CSRF: Generate token for every request

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security, csrf

Right now, we have csrf token per session. And adding this token jsp's using hidden field. following snippet gives only one per session:

```
token = (String) session.getAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_NAME);
    if (null==token) {
        token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        session.setAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_NAME, token);
    }
```

and for every request,

```
//calls the above snippet and this time token will not be null 
String st = CSRFTokenManager.getTokenForSession(request.getSession());
String rt = CSRFTokenManager.getTokenFromRequest(request);
```

here, usings equals to compare the strings and returning either true or false.

my question is, what happens if I try to generate the token for every request without getting the token from session. And while comparing, I will get from the session and request. is this good idea or missing something?

Instead of using the above snippets, I will go with following

```
    //for every request generate a new and set in session
    token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    session.setAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_NAME, token);

    //get the token from session and request and compare
    String st = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_NAME");
    String rt = CSRFTokenManager.getTokenFromRequest(request);
```

Comment: You can generate a token and not store it in session at all. Add it as a hidden field to the form and as a cookie. When you receive the request, compare values of the field and the cookie.

Comment: not sure..but, I think cookies are vulnerable to CSRF attack

Comment: @ user1609085  The idea of the CSRF token is that an attacker tries to send "hidden" request impersonating another user A. The attacker uses some other website where he could inject some malicious javascript code, the important here is that from this site he cannot send the token in the cookie or in an special header (browsers dont let the attacker do that), thats why the token is usually put in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to flip around the flow that you stated above. After every compare you should create a new token.

One large drawback to token-per-request is if the user hits the back button in their browser:

- User visits Page1 and stores `TokenA` in session.
- User clicks a link to Page2, submitting `TokenA`. The app verifies `TokenA` in session and gives the user `TokenB`.
- User hits the back button to go back to Page1, session information is not updated.
- Page1 still only has information for `TokenA`, user clicks a link or submits a form to Page3 submitting `TokenA`, but the session only knows about `TokenB`
- App considers this a CSRF attack

Because of this, you need to take great care of how and when the tokens are updated.

Comment: I need this type of configuration in my application plz suggest me for this type of configuration i can achieve this or not.

Comment: Hi, i know it's an old post, but I am into the same situation right now. Could you please verify my understanding:1) when user visits page 1, String st = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_NAME"); is called and is null. After this String rt = CSRFTokenManager.getTokenFromRequest(request); is called which generates and sets a new value to session attribute. When is the comparison done?

Comment: What will happen if user refreshes the page?

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the solution suggested by Jay, I will suggest you to avoid caching of your web-pages by setting various cache-control headers in the response to client.

Comment: Without some context I think your suggestion is really bad. The flow described by Jay is really not practical at all. GET requests 99% of the time doesn't update data, thats why they are gets, if it does, your system is bad designed. So you end up only protecting POST|PUT|DELETE|HEAD... and for those comming from form the back button situation is not common in a well designed app. usually after posting a form you redirect so you cannot repost the form when going back in browser history